# Android set of dialogs for setting up app

Tags: android, dialog

The first time a user loads my Android app I want to go through a few stages of setting up the app.

Basically I just want a set of dialogs that goes from one step to the next, but I don't know the best way to go about it.

Comment: Check for a setting in your sharedpreferences. And after you do the initialization, set that variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented a similar solution to my app.  I place a breadcrumb in the preferences that indicates it's the first time the app has been run.  I have a "Home" activity that is shown to the user.  In onCreate, I check if the user has run the app before by looking at this preference value.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    if(this.application.getPreferences().isFirstTimeRun())
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, WizardStepOneActivity.class));
    }
    else
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
    }
}
```

If the user has not run the app, I launch a series of activities to walk through (i.e. Wizard-like) to set the initial settings.  By using onActivityResult, I can navigate through the setup steps.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch(requestCode)
    {
    case WIZARD_STEP_1:
        Intent i = new Intent(this, WizardStepTwoActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(i, WIZARD_STEP_2);
        break;
    case WIZARD_STEP_2:
        Intent i = new Intent(this, WizardStepThreeActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(i, WIZARD_STEP_3);
        break;
    case WIZARD_STEP_3:
        //Set the breadcrumb to indicate that the user has set their preferences
        this.application.setFirstTimeRunCompleted();

        //Start main activity
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        break;

    }
```

}

I'm not sure if this is the best way or not, but it seems to work so far.  Obviously, error handling should be in place to make sure they have set up the preferences, so that it is fine to set the breadcrumb.

Hope this helps,
Kevin

Comment: Good to know!  One thought, looking at the code again, is that the creation of a new Intent at each step may prevent information being passed between the wizard steps.  I'm wondering if you can re-use the "data" parameter to launch each step, thereby passing the same Intent (and therefore the same Bundle) between steps.  Anyways...glad it worked out for you!